# Answer Ban Removal Methods

Tags: support, question-answer-ban

I got an answer ban. "We are no longer accepting answer from this account".

So I deleted my minus 1 answers but its still not going. What to do?

Comment: Deleting question is like the worst thing to do in such situation.

Answer (score 8):

That's unfortunate to hear. But I have the answer to your question - More likely, [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) does. (Specially, the question is there to help banned users remove their bans)

> ## Why am I getting that message?
>
> > An automatic filter is in place to ban questions and/or answers from IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor posts.
> >
> > To avoid bypassing the filter its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities. If the other members of the site consistently give your posts a low ranking, you should try to identify the reason(s) for this.
> >
> > Once you have posted too many poorly-received questions or answers, you will be banned from posting more, and you will see the error message.

Alright now, I see that not many of your answers have been negatively received, so what I reckon to be the reason in cause here is

### What you deleted

Let's look back at the mother source:

> Are deleted posts taken into account too?
>
> > Yes, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) and deleted answers count towards an automatic ban.
> >
> > It's not a problem to have deleted posts. But if a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they are not suitable for the site. Posting them consumes time from users who read them, edit them, or respond to them. Therefore deleted posts have an effect on the filter, among many other factors.

## So the big question: What should I do now?

> > **Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. The only way for the ban to be lifted is by *contributing positively* to the site in other ways.**
> >
> > Moderators cannot lift the ban.
> >
> > Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts! As noted above, down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? Then fix them!
> >
> > Note the emphasis on fixing. Do not delete your posts.

In your case I realized that you suddenly posted things that required correcting with accordance to applying a lot of SE rules - which isn't occurring very often to new users - that may have overwhelmed you about here. So I may guide you to some useful posts that say why StackExchange network is like this:

- [Are StackExchange sites simply forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum?s=1|2.2489)
- [Why StackExchange sites are so clean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31168/fk-you-fk-you-and-fk-you-whos-next?s=2|1.1587) This is one of the best aspects about StackExchange. A community of serious experts that get the answer and do not jibber jabber about things.
- [StackOverflow, where we hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) This is irrelevant to your case, but is a good mention on what's going on throughout SE.
- Oh, and also [this: Why SE might feel scary to some people?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202168/why-is-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-so-scary/202171#202171) which reflects a lot of the feeling of some [new] users towards StackExchange. (Sometimes, including myself)

Comment: Thanks for hunting the info down!

Comment: Thank you. It got lifted.

Comment: @jonsca anytime! I don't go hunting! It's just what I do when I feel bored. :)